# How to tune in the right DRC rule for BGA footprint - Altium CircuitMaker

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, altium, bga, drc

According to JLCPCB, they write that their [capability](https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/pcb-capabilities) for the clearance between SMD pad and track is 0.2mm.

[image]

**0.2mm is 7.87401575mil.**

If we look at a GBA processor with 0.8mm pitch.
[image]

Due to the 0.2mm clearance, it will become lots of warnings.

This image show the distance between the pad and the track

[image]

This image show the distance between the clearance and the track

[image]

**Question:**

What is the right rule of tuing to use here if I want to have a track between the pads. The track must be `3.5 mil` as minimum, which is 0.09mm.